# Sublime Text Xdebug Start Debugging (Launch Browser) custom keybinding

Tags: php, sublimetext3, key-bindings

I am wondering how to set a custom keybinding for Sublime Text using xdebug to start debugging with launching the browser. This is my .sublime-keymap file I am using. I tried adding the last key binding to start debugging while launching the browser, but it doesn't work

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent" , "args": { "single_line": false } },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Add Line Before.sublime-macro"} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+s"], "command": "prompt_save_as" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+s"], "command": "save_all" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+m", "ctrl+o"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 2} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+f5"], "command": "Start Debugging (Launch Browser)"},
]
```

There is a key binding for the regular start debugging, which is ctrl+shift+f9, but I want to be able to start the browser because the bug I need to find is when a certain thing happens in my web app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I also remember I was able to "Launch Browser" from Sublime Text, now the otpion is gone and starting the debug doesn't hook on my XAMPP no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using [`Xdebug Client`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Xdebug%20Client), as this is the only `xdebug` package available for Sublime Text 3. If you look at the other keymaps, you'll notice that the `"command"` is `snake_case`, so `"Start Debugging (Launch Browser)"` won't work as a command. To find the command needed, go to the [Github repo](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug) and check out the [`Default.sublime-keymap`](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/blob/master/Default.sublime-keymap) file, which lists all the default key bindings and their associated commands:

```json
[
    {"keys": ["ctrl+f8"], "command": "xdebug_breakpoint"},
    {"keys": ["shift+f8"], "command": "xdebug_conditional_breakpoint"},
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f5"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "run"}},
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f6"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_over"}},
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f7"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_into"}},
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f8"], "command": "xdebug_continue", "args": {"command": "step_out"}},
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f9"], "command": "xdebug_session_start"},
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f10"], "command": "xdebug_session_stop"},
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f11"], "command": "xdebug_layout", "args": {"keymap" : true}}
]
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> is bound to the `"xdebug_session_start"` command, so just enter that in your user `.sublime-keymap` file and you should be all set. However, you should also note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> already has a command mapped to it, so you'll need to make the decision of whether you want to override that command, or pick a different key binding.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and easy-to-understand answer!

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to solve this problem is adding argument `launch_browser` to `xdebug_session_start`, like these:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+f9"], "command": "xdebug_session_start", "args": {"launch_browser" : true}},
```

It would be Ok.

the resolve is from: http://www.mattkirwan.com/programming-tools/2015/10/22/customising-sublime-text-xdebug-shortcuts.html